# Access Denied on Php Login

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-state, session-variables

I **have a buyer form, called "Buyer.php":**

```
<form method="post" action="check_buyer.php" id="LoggingInBuyer">
    <div style="width:265px;margin:0; padding:0; float:left;">
    <label>Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><a href="#">Forgot Username?</span></a></label> <br />
    <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="userName" tabindex="1" class="required" /></div>
    <div style="width:265px;margin:0; padding:0; float:right;">
    <label>Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><a href="#">Forgot Password?</span></a></label> <br />
    <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="password"  name="userPass" tabindex="2" class="required" /></div>
    <div class="clearB"> </div>
    <input type="submit" style="width:100px; margin:10px 200px;" id="UserRegSubmit" name="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3" />
</form>
```

**A file called check_buyer.php (in the same dir):**

```
<?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged include()

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        header( 'Location: buyer/' ); # return true if sessions are made and login creds are valid
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
    return false;
}

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');

$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt, uUserType FROM User WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";

function validateUser($ifUserExists['uID'], $ifUserExists['uUserType']) {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $uID;
    $_SESSION['uUserType'] = $uUserType; // 1 for buyer - 2 for merchant
}

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}else {
    validateUser();
}
// If User *has not* logged in yet, keep on /login
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

// This is now throwing error of: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in on line 23 which is `function validateUser($ifUserExists['uID'], $ifUserExists['uUserType']) {`

**and the file "index.php" in the buyer/ directory:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['uUserType']!=1)
{ 
    die("You may not view this page. Access denied.");
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    return (isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']);
}

//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1){
        #echo "<a href='../logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        require_once('buyer_profile.php');
    }else{
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

The point of this is that when a username and password is entered, the user is logged in and directed to `/buyer/index.php`, to the `buyer` portion of that website. It seems everytime I login with the dummy credentials I made to test, it just blurts out : `You may not view this page. Access denied`. But, then if I go back by pressing back arrow in browser it has me `logged in` and `showing a link to logout`.

I did some trouble shooting:
1) Shown here, to test my `sql query` is fine and indeed it is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2b5z.png

2)Tried `choing` out `echo 'the userid: ' . $userid;` before it whines about `You may not view..` and it doesn't print anything.

How do I go about getting this `userID`? I double checked the field names in the database and all is fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick check, it looks like you're setting `$_SESSION['uUserType'] = $userType` in `validateUser()`, but don't seem to be passing in `$userType` itself to that function. So `$_SESSION['uUserType']` won't be `1`, but `$_SESSION['valid']` will be, because you're setting it to that in `validateUser()`.

I suspect you should be passing valid data in to `validateUser` in order to set it into the session.

e.g.

```
validateUser($ifUserExists['uID'], $ifUserExists['uUserType']);

function validateUser($uID, $uUserType) {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $uID;
    $_SESSION['uUserType'] = $uUserType; // 1 for buyer - 2 for merchant
}
```

Comment: do I then have to define $ifUserExists ?

Comment: No, you already have, here: `$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);`  That will return an array that contains the fields you selected in your query.

Comment: Please see the error I'm now experiencing and the updated check_buyer.php file.

Comment: The function definition should just be as I indicated above, i.e. `function validateUser($uID, $uUserType)`, you use the specific array keys as parameters when *calling* it.

Comment: so should function validateUser read:  `$_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $uID;
    $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1;`

Comment: If you want `uUserType` to be 1, yes. I assumed you'd want the column you selected from the table, hence `$_SESSION['uUserType'] = $uUserType;` in my example, and passing it in to the function. If you don't need that, then sure, just set it to 1.

Comment: I'm completely confused now, I want the value of uUserType, which value will ALWAYS be 1

Comment: i'm still not understanding how this stops a person from just typing in /login/merchant and all of a sudden their a merchant..